# combine google maps javascripts into one

Tags: performance

When I run my website through Pingdom Tool test, it says I have to many external JavaScript, and these should be combined into as fewer as possible.

Is there a way to combine the following scripts into one (or as fewer as possible)?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/common.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/controls.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/geocoder.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/infowindow.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/map.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/marker.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/onion.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/util.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/Authent ... htAKU6FT4fAM4&callback=_xdc_._7duho1&token=81040
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/Geocode ... htAKU6FT4fAM4&callback=_xdc_._ja54gz&token=80119
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/Viewpor ... 0000&7b0&8e0&callback=_xdc_._vi8nk4&token=113027
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/Viewpor ... 00000&7b0&8e0&callback=_xdc_._xp4b9k&token=35277
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAA1E2Rcxs8vYcJArt1GKhtAKU6FT4fAM4
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3 ... !4e3!12m1!5b1&callback=_xdc_._7rk4vn&token=43082
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3 ... !4e3!12m1!5b1&callback=_xdc_._7z4nki&token=24193
```

Comment: same question for me

Comment: same for me too